# Battery charge suddenly drops from 100% to 0%

Tags: 18.04, power-management, battery

I have a DELL LATITUDE E7450 with battery issues. When it is fully charged (displaying 100%), after some time the battery charge drops suddenly from 100% to 0%. When I unplug the charger, it warns me that the computer will shut down, and it indeed shutdowns after a few minutes as if the battery was completely empty.

When I replug the charger with the battery at 0% charge after the bug, the whole system is much slower (meaning that it takes a lot of time to even load a web page or do other stuff), and I have to hard reboot to have the system back to normal.

Finally what I came across is that if I remove the battery (while it's at 0%) and put it back, the display will be correct, and if I unplug and replug the charger after that there are no problems on the system.

The bug is usually happening if I let my computer plugged for a night. So I guess after several hours of charge, the bug happens.

I'm running on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, and in the BIOS the state of my battery is Excellent.

**[EDIT 1]**
Battery capacity according to `Power Statistics`:

[image: This is what I get with power statirstics]

And this is the output of `upower -i upower -e | grep 'BAT'`:

```
 /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

Comment: Did you try it with other OS like Windows, to make sure that it is not a hardware problem

Comment: Install an app called `power statistics`, select `laptop battery` in the left column, and post a screenshot with `energy when full` and `energy(design)`. Or just edit the question with the output of "upower -i `upower -e | grep 'BAT'`" command

Comment: I have edited the post with the information you required